# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file

Tags: php

Просмотрел около 10 вопросов по схожей проблеме в англоязычной версии, однако в тех случаях проблемы с if-конструкциями, функциями, т.д.
Моя проблема заключается в присваивании action форме.

`<form method="post" action="<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
</form>`

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file in D:...php on line 5

Comment: Пробовал заменять " " на ' ' , помещать аргумент функции echo в скобки, удалять тег окончания ?>.

Comment: Добавьте остальной код страницы

Comment: @MatveiGavriluk получили эту ошибку, когда пробовали удалить тег окончания `?>`? Код из вопроса работает.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
</form>
```

Comment: Интересно, кто минус поставил, когда приведенный мной код записи самый оптимальный и рабочий?)

Comment: Я не ставил, спасибо.

Comment: Также работает 
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">.